# How to pass HttpServletRequestWrapper in grails filter chain

Tags: java, grails, filter

I have created a CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper to read the inputStream multiple times. From the grails Filter class I am calling the wrapper and getting the wrapper object without any problem and that object has what I needed.

Now after receiving the CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper how to make the grails filter to use this new HttpServletRequest instead of the actual one.

In java we can call `filterChain.doFilter(customWrapper,response)` but to do that I have to write a custom filter that implements Filter and do the necessary steps etc..

My question is, Is there a easy way in grails to pass the newly formed requestWrapper to rest of the filters??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Grails filters don't provide a way to wrap the request. You should use regular servlet filter